# Locking Loopback API

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a running Loopback API that's working fine.

This API will be consumed by an APP (iPhone and/or Android) and all the requests to the API will be made inside the APP.

I want to lock the API so only logged users (in this case the API) can get any kind of information from there.

I am using the built-in Users model and creating a user to get the token and then sending it together with the API call and it works just fine but I've read this token expires.

Is there any way to make a permanent token and I change it only if I want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Permanent AccessToken in loopback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738285/creating-permanent-accesstoken-in-loopback)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanent token on loopback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622211/permanent-token-on-loopback)